# How to create parallel child processes using fork

Tags: c++, linux, process, fork

I'm trying to achieve the below picture:
[image: image1]

I intend to create N parallel child processes.

I tried the following for creating 5 child processes:

```
pid_t pid;
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) 
{
    pid = fork();
    if (pid) {
        //Parent
    } else if (pid == 0) {
        cout<<"Child: "<<getppid()<<endl;
    } else {
        cout<<"fork error\n";
    }
}
```

And I get some output like that:

```
Child: 3636
Child: 3632
Child: 28287
Child: 3642
Child: 28287
Child: 28287
Child: 3633
Child: 28287
Child: 28287
Child: 28287
```

But it seems like I get more child processes than I need. And another point is that, NOT all child processes come from the same parent, i.e they have different parents.

Is it possible to do something like that correctly? If yes, how could it be done?

Comment: A suggestion: did you notice your `"fork error\n"` is a dead code? also, `cout` is `c++`.

Comment: What do you mean is a dead code? for `cout` being in `c++` does not matter

Comment: Check your `if..else` loop condition. upon failure, `fork()` returns `-1`. you have to change your condition check accordingly.

Comment: "for cout being in c++ does not matter"... thats true, but you say you are in c and there simply no `cout` exists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your child is resuming the loop and forking its own children. You should put something like an `break` right after the `cout` in the child process.